# Story identification: A piece of the Sun's surface "peels away", and Earth must be pushed to a new orbit

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recall the name of a novel or short story I read many years ago, with a fairly similar premise to [The Day the Earth Caught Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Caught_Fire) or [The Midnight Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Midnight_Sun), but it was definitely written, not film or TV.

What I remember:

- Earth is already in the midst of some climatic disaster with runaway temperatures (similar to [Heat](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/80122.Heat), but with a different ending).
- **A piece of the Sun's surface "peels off"**, causing the lethal temperature of the Sun's interior to "radiate out" - right into Earth's orbital path  (**this was the unique element of this story**).
- USA and Russia each trigger nuclear bombs to "push" Earth to a safer orbit.
- However, because they were both unaware of the other's efforts, the combined explosions push Earth away from the Sun instead, causing Earth to freeze.

Google just reveals the stories I've already mentioned because of the similarities, but it wasn't any of these.  Anyone?

Comment: I think it's safe to say this wasn't published in *Analog* or *Asimov's*...